# Managed Package hidden permission set

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have a managed package repo that includes a single Permission Set. That Permission Set seems to be enabled for all users when I install. However, I can't see this Permission Set anywhere in Setup.

Is there some metadata that is specifying this behavior that I am not finding? I have another package where I would like to add the same functionality.

I have looked through the package metadata and reviewed the ISV guide, but so far I do not know how to replicate this.